# Angular MVC View only Structure problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm geting problems with angularjs structure. I pretend to have a translation controller or service or wathever and one controller per group of pages (I will explauin that point).

The idea is an index page that loads all the .js files and .css (that are global on the entire web site). That page will load the login file (in it´s body), with its angular controller. Then it will load a template with nav, header, footer, etc... templates, and in the article section I pretend to load diferent pages (links in the nav menu) each page  (or group) with its controller. I'm starting with angularjs and it doesn't works. The idea will be similar at next code:

index (reduced for the example):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html **ng-app="app" ng-controller="translationsCtrl"**>
      <head> 
        <title>something</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>

        <!--GLOBAL STYLES (WILL BE MORE, ONLY EXAMPLE)-->
        <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
       </head>

        <body> 
        <div ng-controller="loginCtrl" ng-include="'views/login.html'"></div>

        <!--GLOBAL SCRIPTS (WILL BE MORE, ONLY EXAMPLE)-->
        <script src="assets/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="controllers/translationsCtrl.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

in login.html it will be like this:

```
<!--STUFF-->
<script src="controllers/loginCtrl.js"></script>
```

controllers will be:
loginCtrl.js:

```
angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('loginCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.login = 'login';
    })
```

translationsCtrl.js

```
angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('translationsCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.text = 'text';
    });
```

how can I do something similar working? Are there any better method for doing it? The web app is to huge so I can't use requirejs or simplepage angular.

Comment: You dont need to implement your own way of loading pages, read angularjs routing or ui-router

Comment: but with ui-router I cant preload templates. If I want to load a login page with x format an then I want to laod a template with nav, footer, header, etc and the rest of pages in the article section without reloading the footer, header and those all stuff I can´t do that with routing (or I don´t know how to). Probably with 2 routing files different, but I don´t know.

Comment: you can still do it with nested states in ui-router https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views

Comment: Oh thankls I diodn't knowed that method